# Populate list with the same number

Tags: c#, linq

How I can convert this code to LINQ?

```
var TcData = new List<double>();

for(int i=0;i< numberTcs ;++i)
{
    TcData.Add(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TcData = Enumerable.Repeat(-1d, numberTcs).ToList();
```

Comment: This results in a `List<Int32>`, not `List<double>`. It should be `Enumerable.Repeat<double>(...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
TcData = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat<double>(-1, numberTcs));
```